Build Apk Flutter
My flutter project uses googlefont poppins. But when I build the apk, the font changes to default. Can anyone help me solve this?
I have tried to make it a theme, it still doesn't work. I think my laptop is the problem, I have tried restarting the laptop but it still doesn't work.

Could you please share the pubspec.yaml file.
Please verify that you've enabled internet permission.

I added the font package that I downloaded to assets. Strangely it works even without me using the font family(so I just use googlefonts.poppins() on the textstyle)
